# I am facing problem with the bootstrap 3 CSS class="thumbnail"

Tags: html, css

I wanted three images in each row...

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2103864/pexels-photo-2103864.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1476321/pexels-photo-1476321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected it to be inside the border and all the images should have been of same size (three in each row) ...But its not.. help...

Comment: Are you using a framework, or did you write your own css, because right now I know its probably one on top of the other going down?

Comment: yes its bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is remove `&w=500` from the image URLs so they scale to the dynamic width of the Bootstrap grid, and maybe also change the class on the columns to `col-md-4` or `col-sm-4` to make sure the images sit next to each other on smaller screens.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2103864/pexels-photo-2103864.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1476321/pexels-photo-1476321.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want all three images to have the same height as well, you could do something like this:

```
.thumbnail img {
    max-height: 300px;    
}
```

To achieve true dynamic uniformity, you should look at using [Bootstrap 4 card groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-groups) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have `<div class="thumbnail">`, but [the built-in bootstrap 3 thumbnail classname](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/#images) is `<div class="img-thumbnail">`.

You say you want all images to be the same size, but your images have different proportions. Their pixel sizes are: 500x333, 500x750, and 500x375. What behavior do you want exactly? You could force them to all be the same height and width by setting adding styles for `height=500px; width=500px;`, but then the images will be distorted and squashed.